# .Net what new Regex(@"[ ]{2,}", options) means

Tags: .net, regex

What's happening in this code snippet ?

```
    RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.None;
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"[ ]{2,}", options);
    string outStr = regex.Replace(inStr, @" ");
```

What I am looking for is to replace any sequences of "white" spaces ( including TAB, CR, LF )   with a single space.

Comment: If you want all white spaces, you should use `@"\s{2,}"` or `@"\s+"`, as Vash suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's break it down:

```
[ ]          <-- matches a single space
{2,}         <-- previous token is repeated 2 or more times
```

So this would match 2 or more consecutive spaces.

Then the .Replace call, this would replace those sequences of 2 or more spaces with just one space.

Answer (score 3):

`[ ]` denotes a character group (in this case only a single whitespace)
`{2,}` means "at least 2 times"

so, this code replaces multiple occurences of a space with a single one

which is much easier to write (and read) as: `" +"` (one or more spaces) and then replace them with a single one (shouldn't be slower after all)

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"[ ]{2,}", options);
```

Creates a regular expression object, that will look for occurrences of 2 or more adjacent spaces. The `[ ]` creates a character group that contains a space - it could have been written as a , but would then be less readable is my guess. The `{2,}` means 2 or more (unbounded) of the previous character (or character group).

See [this](http://regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx) handy RegEx cheat sheet for .NET regex syntax.

This line finds all such occurrences and replaces them with one space:

```
string outStr = regex.Replace(inStr, @" ");
```

The replace function finds all matches of the regex in the first string parameter, and replaces them with the second string.

In both cases, there is no need for a verbatim string literal (starting with `@`).

Answer (score 2):

@ - verbatim string literal; the characters are not interpreted till next quote

[ ] - in this brackets we specify whit characters are allowed or not. This([ ]) any whitespace it is possible that author wanted to use replace only space but for this should be used pattern \s

{2,} - At least two time

Probably this Regex had to remove double spaces